# Generating 8-bit keys

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, jsse

I want to store multiple 8-bit keys and store in JSSE keystore, is it possible to do that with keytoo?

something with

```
keytool -genkeypair
```

Comment: 8-bit keys? Which algorithm uses 8 bit keys? Who would want a cipher algorithm that needs a maximum of 256 attempts to crack? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: no algorithm,but i want it for some other purpose not encryption

Comment: Then use "some other" mechanism. The keytool is used to generate cryptographic keys. Not to generate random bytes.